# Making an HTML tab select when the page loads using the onload command using

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a tab be preselected when the webpage loads. Essentially when you clikc the tab in the sidebar it will turn grey but when the webpage first loads it is unselected.

Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example title</title>
</head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"> 
<div>
    <div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-black w3-card-2" style="width:130px">
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="openLink(event, 'Ex1')">Example 1</button>
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="openLink(event, 'Ex2')">Example 2</button>
</div>
<div style="margin-left:130px">
    <div id="Ex1" class="w3-container tab w3-animate-left" >
        <h2>Example 1 header</h2>
        <p>
            Example 1 text
        </p>
    </div>  
    <div id="Ex2" class="w3-container tab" style="display:none">
    <h2>Example 2 Header</h2>
        <p>
            Example 2 text.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function openLink(evt, animName) {
      var i, x, tablinks;
      x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
         tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" w3-grey", "");
      }
          document.getElementById(animName).style.display = "block";
      evt.currentTarget.className += " w3-grey";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't match the right ID in you onclick attribute of your button **Ex1** and **Ex2** instead of **Example1** and **Exemple2**

```js
  window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementsByClassName("w3-button")[0].click();
  }
function openLink(evt, animName) {
      var i, x, tablinks;
      x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
         tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" w3-grey", "");
      }
          document.getElementById(animName).style.display = "block";
      evt.target.className += " w3-grey";
    }
```

```css
.w3-grey {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-black w3-card-2" style="width:130px">
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="openLink(event, 'Example1')">Example 1</button>
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="openLink(event, 'Example2')">Example 2</button>
</div>
<div style="margin-left:130px">
    <div id="Example1" class="w3-container tab w3-animate-left" style="display:none">
        <h2>Example 1 header</h2>
        <p>
            Example 1 text
        </p>
    </div>  
    <div id="Example2" class="w3-container tab" style="display:none">
    <h2>Example 2 Header</h2>
        <p>
            Example 2 text.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well thank you, I changed the data values from their original tags. But that also does nothing to help my situation. It's not caused by the event IDs.

Comment: I edit my reponse. You many choice to do that, you can set it on your HTML :
 - keep your code and just add the class in your button
 - set an initial state in the window.onload in js
 - or like my exemple trigger the event to init your state

Comment: Thank you so much! I edited the values to fit my actual page and it works perfectly! Ty Ty Ty.